# i have made a pvc,why my openpai dashboard can't see any storages?

Tags: openpai

here are my `pvc.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: csi-s3-pvc
  namespace: pai-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: csi-s3
```

and here is my dashboard:
[image: my openpai dashboard]

is my Authority wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call group API to link this PVC to OpenPAI group. Please refer: https://openpai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/cluster-admin/how-to-set-up-storage.html#assign-storage-to-pai-groups

Comment: thanks for your replay,i have followed the document.but it gives me a new error "Invalid storage server type".  does openpai not support s3 storage?such as minio;